# How can I add new codecs for matlab?

Tags: matlab, codec

Is there any way to load new codecs for matlab?
It only supports basic codecs and filters.
I need to use uncompperessed videos in matlab

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, you can use all GStreamer plugins.

On Windows, you can use DirectShow codecs, including [ffdshow](http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/). Alternatively, you can use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) to transcode video or write the frames of a video into a series of images.

Comment: Have you actually sucessfully tried using ffdshow codecs with matlab's avifile or similar?

Comment: Yeah, absolutely, although in recent versions one uses `VideoReader` and `VideoWriter`.

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is NO, you cannot add new codecs. I presume you wish to use these codecs with the Matlab functions `avifile` and `addframe` etc. Matlab only supports a very limited and outdated set of codecs.

To get MPEG encoding you could try [mpgwrite](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/309) and [mpgread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/308-mpgread) on The Mathworks file exchange. Or for further information see [this](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/tech-notes/1200/1204.html) support link.