# OpenCV has different RGB values from Matlab?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to transfer one matlab project to C++ code. However, when I trying to read an mp4 video by frame, the RGB values for each pixels is very different from Matlab. Does it mean OpenCV used a different RGB value representation? If so, how can I change the OpenCV value to Matlab? Otherwise I cannot verify my implementation are right by checking values.

For example:
I am trying to check the point(0,0) values in OpenCV and Matlab. OpenCV gives the following result: `blue=106 green=105 red=102`
However, in Matlab, the result is: `blue=85 green=86 red=83`
I tried to get the RGB value in point(0,0) for every 200 frames which is point(1,1) in Matlab.

The C++ code to get RGB value in OpenCV are:

```
Mat img;
number = 0;
VideoCapture cap(filename_input_video);
if(!cap.isOpened()) {
    printf("No video to Read!\n");
    return -1;
}

for( ; ; ) {
    cap >> img;
    if(img.empty())
        break;
    number++;

    for(int i=0; i<img.rows; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<img.cols; j++) {
            int blue = img.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0];
            int green = img.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1];
            int red = img.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2];

            if(number == 200 && i==0 && j==0) {
                printf("blue=%d green=%d red=%d", blue, green, red);
            }
        }
    }

    if(number == 200) {
        number = 0;
    }
}
```

The Matlab code is:

```
OBJ = VideoReader(filename_source);
fBlock = 200;
nFrame = get(OBJ, 'NumberOfFrames');
nBlock = ceil(nFrame / fBlock);

for iBlock = 1:nBlock
    display(['Processing video 1 block #' num2str(iBlock) '...']);
    start_index = (iBlock-1)*fBlock+1;
    end_index = min(iBlock*fBlock, nFrame);

    vSource = read(OBJ,[start_index end_index]);
    display(['red ' num2str(vSource(1,1,1,200))]);
    display(['green ' num2str(vSource(1,1,2,200))]);
    display(['blue ' num2str(vSource(1,1,3,200))]);
```

How should i fix this problem?

Comment: Please provide code and and example data which allows to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Yes, I have already updated.

Comment: The code provided doesn't reproduce any issue. First, there's no Matlab code. Second, the OpenCV code is too general. If you claim that the RGB values are wrong for (0, 0) for one frame, then show code that checks/displays that. Lastly, it might help to have the data in question that causes the issue.

Comment: I have included the Matlab code, it shouldn't be wrong.

Comment: You should compare RGB value of single image read from disc. If you read frame/image captured from video, there can be difference as the video decoder can be different. Try this and let us know.

Comment: @PervezAlam Yes, you are right! Reading images from disc are correct. But what I need is to read from video, so how should i do in order to keep the values the same with Matlab? Otherwise, it would be difficult for me to know if my implementation are right.

Comment: I am extending my comment as answer. It may be helpful for others too.

Answer (score 2):

To verify the difference, you should compare RGB value of single image read from disc. Reading identical values here shows your code is probably fine and there is a difference in decoding.

*What is probably happening* : If you read frame/image captured from video, there can be difference as the video decoder can be different for OpenCV(default is ffmpeg) and MATLAB. Different decoder can handle some events/errors differently and there is no guarantee of identical decoding.

*Suggested Solution* :

**1) Same decoder** - If you need both tools to be identical in result, use same decoder for both. Either change decoder for OpenCV or for MATLAB. If you google, you will find few article on how to do this. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002573/how-can-i-add-new-codecs-for-matlab) and [this](http://videoio.sourceforge.net/) can be helpful.

**2) Same video** -  Use any decoder(I prefer ffmpeg) to convert video to raw format first. Now you can use it on both tool without fear of diff ;). Here is a command to get raw from compresed:

```
`c:/> ffmpeg -i compressed_or_original_video.avi -vcodec rawvideo raw_converted_video.avi`
```

Answer (score -1):

No! it does not! you see different result because C++ array indexing starts from zero while matlab/octave indexing starts from 1.

Comment: I have already updated my question. Yes, I do know the indexing so I check the (0,0) in C++ and (1,1) in Matlab, there is no indexing error.

Comment: what about i & j? do you use the correct indexing on them too?

Comment: try to check your code on a zero valued (black) pixel or 255(white) pixel, if they are not the same either then there is definitely something wrong with your code or you are neglecting something.

Comment: i,j is the index of image point positions. I have already updated.

Comment: which frame of the video are you accessing in the double for loops and which frame did you accessed on matlab? are you sure the frames are the same?

Comment: I have updated question. I check the pixel values every 200 frames. However, even I check the frame 190-210 in Matlab, there is still no single match with OpenCV.